# weird VB.Net behavior

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have this program in vb.net that prints the text on the first form with a textbox and a label to the second form.. It works fine..but when I transferred the text and the labels of the second form that came from the first form to the third form it gives me an error here is my codes thanks in advance for the help :)

```
    Public Class Form3
    Private frm2 As New Form2
    Private xfrm3 As New Form4
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim label21 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label21.Text = label21.Text
        Dim label22 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label22.Text = label22.Text
        Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
        Dim textbox2 As New TextBox
        If textbox1.Text = frm2.Label22.Text And textbox2.Text = frm2.Label24.Text Then

            xfrm3.Label1.Text = xfrm3.Label1.Text + 1
            Form4.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks again :)
EDIT: Right now there is no error message but when I click the button nothing happens

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: right now there is no error message but when I click the button nothing happens

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense (semantically). This isn't the way you'd usually create controls, they wouldn't even be placed on a form. The new TextBox instances will not have any value for their Text property, making the condition you've specified impossible to ever be true. You'd have to set `textbox1.Text = label21.Text` for it to ever work in this scenario. You also want to use `xfrm3.Show()` instead of `Form4.Show()`. Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens beacause this :

```
If textbox1.Text = frm2.Label22.Text And textbox2.Text = frm2.Label24.Text Then
```

Is not a satisified. I think the second condition is not "correct"

```
textbox2.Text = frm2.Label24.Text Then
```

textbox2.Text maybe is empty because is just created, but frm2.Label24.Text have a different value.

I can't understand totally your code... try to set an explicit name on your textbox object and give a chance to the debug... maybe can help you.